# Backdrop opacity don't work in bulma modal with method .show, only with showModal

Tags: javascript, dialog, modal-dialog, popup, bulma

Im trying to build a website for portfolio, and im using bulma navbar, got a button to switch themes that open up a modal, but de body dont "blur" since i changed the method in JS to modal.show, modal.showModal before, even with dialog::backdrop in CSS.

```
const switchTheme = document.getElementById("switchTheme")
const modal = document.querySelector("dialog")
const buttonClose = document.getElementById("cancelModal")
const saveTheme = document.getElementById("saveThemeBtn")

switchTheme.onclick = function() {
  modal.show()
}
buttonClose.onclick = function() {
  modal.close()
}
saveTheme.onclick = function() {
  modal.close()
}
```

```
dialog {
  width: 33rem;
  max-width: 90vw;
  height: 40rem;
  max-height: 90vw;
  text-align: center;
  top: 15%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: var(--color4);
}
dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
dialog h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 4rem;
    background-color: var(--color2);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
dialog span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: var(--color2);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding-inline: 3rem;
}
```